# int.TryParse syntatic sugar

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

`int.TryPrase` is great and all, but there is only one problem...it takes at least two lines of code to use:

```
int intValue;
string stringValue = "123";
int.TryParse(stringValue, out intValue);
....
```

Of course I can do something like:

```
string stringValue = "123";
int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue) ? 0 : stringValue);
```

on just one line of code.

**How can I perform some magic to get int.TryParse to use a one liner, or is there yet a third alternative out there?**

*Note: Bezden answered the question best, but in reality I plan on using Reddog's solution.*

Comment: Whilst a little late to this party...I totally agree, it would be nice to have TryParse as a one liner, but the suggestions here are not very nice. C# 6.0 had a language proposal that would have allowed this syntax...                                                                                                    bool result = int.TryParse("123", out int value); // value = 123

Comment: related: if you are casting int to int? you can do `int.TryParse("string", out int result) ? result: result`, so the compiler won't get mad

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
int intValue = int.TryParse(stringValue, out intValue) ? intValue : 0;
```

Comment: Nice.  The only problem, of course, is that you can't differentiate between a bad value and a 0 in the input string... it takes away the point of using TryParse()

Comment: you beat me to it :). +1 for same solution :)

Comment: @James: I don't agree... that dependes on the context.

Comment: Well, if the user enters "gobbledygook" in a textbox that expects an int, do you want to blaze ahead using '0' instead?  Or do you want to tell the user about their error and let them correct it to get the results they're really after?

Comment: ...aaaand I just learned you can use a variable as an "out" param in the same line you declare it. Thanks!

Comment: How does this code not scare people? I much prefer @Reddog's extension method.

Comment: Extension methods are generally preferred to a longer line like the one above... but in this case it doesn't take away the issue that you're assigning a default value when the string is invalid.

Comment: @James: Sorry... only thought about the case when input is null :). Think it is time for bed. And I agree with @Joel!

Comment: @Joel, @James: Indeed, you're right in the situations you describe, however, my question is of a less specific nature.

Comment: I take back my comment about the extension method... I see Reddog is explicitly requiring a default value value for when the conversion fails.  Which means the caller is making an active decision to use a default value if the string is invalid.  +1 to Reddog

Comment: There are some assumptions made here about how the OP, or anyone else for that mater would want to use the code. Also the question is not about should it be in an extension method or not, the above could equally be encapsulated in an extension method. Using the above with the new C#7 features allowing a variable to be declared inline with the out statement is just what I needed for my linq query. Thanks Vlad

Answer (score 44):

Maybe use an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int TryParse(this string input, int valueIfNotConverted)
    {
        int value;
        if (Int32.TryParse(input, out value))
        {
            return value;
        }
        return valueIfNotConverted;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
string x = "1234";
int value = x.TryParse(0);
```

**Edit**: And of course you can add the obvious overload that already sets the default value to zero if that is your wish.

Comment: +1 You might want to include the usage `int x = "123".TryParse(1);`

Comment: I wanted to add the same solution as above with int num = "123".ToInt(); but you were faster! for that get +1

Answer (score 25):

This answer is only for those who use **at least C# 7**.

You can now declare the out parameter inline.

```
int.TryParse("123", out var result);
```

Exemplary usage:

```
if (int.TryParse("123", out var result)) {
    //do something with the successfully parsed integer
    Console.WriteLine(result);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("That wasn't an integer!");
}
```

MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables

Comment: I love this improvement in C# 7

Answer (score 4):

I would create an extension method out of this.

```
public static int? AsInt32(this string s)
{
    int value;
    if (int.TryParse(s, out value))
        return value;

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution here because in one line we get the successful parsed value and we can still differentiate between a string that doesn't parse and the string "0"

Comment: Only for nullable ints though...

Comment: Not only for nullable ints. It will just return a null if it fails to parse.

Answer (score 2):

One last addition to this NINE year-old question :). Bool parsing is a little different because if parsing fails, you don't want to return a default value, you want to return a NULL. This line does this (as of C# 7, I think):

```
return bool.TryParse(value, out bool result) ? (bool?)result : null;
```

That cast of the result is necessary, otherwise it cannot reconcile the differing types of the two return values.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything really beautiful, but if you like this you get it down to one row:

```
string stringValue = "123"
int intValue = int.TryParse(stringValue, out intValue) ? intValue : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [StringExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.stringextensions_methods%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) class.  It contains an [AsInt(String,Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548416%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) extension method that will attempt to convert a string and if unsuccessful populate it with the supplied Int32 value as default.

Example:

```
var intValue = "123".AsInt(-1);
```

Comment: I don't have that method accessable by default ?! (.net Framework 4.5)

Answer (score 1):

```
int val2 = "asd".AsInt(-1); 
//Output : -1
 int val3 = "123".AsInt(-1); 
//Output : 123
```

You need to have `System.Web.WebPages` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 7.0+ you can use [inline variable declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0018).

- If parse successes - intValue = its parsed value.
- If parse fails - intValue = 0.

Code:

```
int.TryParse(stringValue, out int intValue);
```

Drawback:

You cannot differentiate between a 0 value and a non parsed value.

Answer (score 0):

You do not WANT to make int.TryParse() one line.  Why?  Because you can't make an assignment to intValue if the input string isn't a valid integer.  The whole point of TryParse() is to allow you to test for good input and degrade gracefully, rather than having to catch an exception.

Int.TryParse() is already a shortcut so you don't have to test for a valid int and do the assignment in two steps... that's as far as you want to take it.

Comment: Thanks, but I disagree to all of your points.  They are simply not true.

Answer (score 0):

This technically isn't the most efficient as it parses the string twice, but it does get it into one line.
Result as `Nullable<int>`:

```
int? ToInt(string value) => int.TryParse(value, out _) ? int.Parse(value) : (int?)null;
```