# Trying to use TryParse in a property getter; wondering if code can be done on a single line

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
private double Input1
{
    get
    {
        double x;
        return double.TryParse(Input1TextBox.Text, out x) ?
            x * (Prefix1ComboBox.SelectedItem as MetricPrefix).Multiplier : double.NaN;
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there's anyway to omit the variable declaration and get this all on one line, or if this is the only possible way.

Comment: Not possible using `TryParse`. Might be possible with `Parse` but you would have to ensure somehow the input is always parseable to a `double`.

Comment: There's another answer that covers this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620565/int-tryparse-syntatic-sugar - look for RedDog's extension method answer.

Comment: I was able to ensure that 'Input1TextBox.Text' is always parseable to 'double', rae1n.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own `Util` class with custom `TryParse` which would return `double?` instead:

```
public static class Util
{
    public static double? TryParse(string source)
    {
        double x;
        if (double.TryParse(source, out x))
            return x;
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
return (Util.TryParse(Input1TextBox.Text) ?? double.NaN) * (Prefix1ComboBox.SelectedItem as MetricPrefix).Multiplier;
```

It uses the fact that `double.NaN` multiplied by other number gives `NaN` as well.

Comment: make it an extension method for added awesomeness

Answer (score 1):

It can as of 2021 in C#7 (possible earlier, unconfirmed), using modern notation.

```cs
class MainForm
{
    //...

    private double Input1 => 
        double.TryParse(Input1TextBox.Text, out double x) ? x * (Prefix1Combo.SelectedItem as MetricPrefix).Multiplier : double.NaN;
   
    //...
}
```

You simply denote the type (`double` in this example) along with the `out` parameter modifier, which will effectively create a local variable of the name passed in the parameter modifier to be used anywhere in the code AFTER called, in-line.

Note that the type could also be inferred with `var` instead of the type, and the legacy notation which is more along the lines of how it was originally written:

```cs
class MainForm
{
    //...

    private double Input1 
    {
        return double.TryParse(Input1TextBox.Text, out var x) ?
            x * (Prefix1ComboBox.SelectedItem as MetricPrefix).Multiplier : double.NaN;
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Hello, your answer does not exactly match the one from the question

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. However, is this a major problem? You can mask this by creating an extension method to do it for you though, if it's not aesthetically pleasing:

```
get
{
    return Input1TextBox.Text.ConvertTo<double>(double.Nan);
}
```

And implement the extension method there to do the defaulting.

Comment: Not a major problem by any means. I was just curious of the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only possible way, unless you decide to cheat by making `x` a class member instead of a local. Or if you decide to cheat by hiding everything inside another method.

There is no real benefit in cutting down the number of newlines though.

Answer (score 0):

No you need to declare the variable first to use TryParse.