# Initiation in C# - Data and Exceptions handling

Tags: c#

My name is Carlos and i recently began to learn programming (completely from scratch) through an E-learning class. My tutor is using C# as an introductory language. I searched in the forum and although i found somewhat similar problems, they don't address my current doubts as most questions are of a more advanced content. 
I'm having a bit of trouble in a exercise regarding Data and Exceptions handling, specifically in the following exercise:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int x;
        var nr_de_produtos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int Máximo_por_caixa = 20;
        var total_em_falta = Máximo_por_caixa - nr_de_produtos;
        string aviso;
        switch (nr_de_produtos)
        {
            case 0:
                aviso = "Caixa vazia";
                break;
            case 20:
                aviso = "Caixa cheia";
                break;
            default:
                aviso = "número de unidades em falta:" + total_em_falta;
                break;
        }

        if (int.TryParse(nr_de_produtos, out x))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Insira o próximo número");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Não foi inserido um número. Fim da aplicação");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(aviso);
    }
}
```

It results in the following errors:

Compilation error (line 25, col 7): The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string, out int)' has some invalid arguments

Compilation error (line 25, col 20): Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

The objective is to address the input of the user and turn a string into an int. I believe i´m using int.Parse and int.TryParse wrongly, but not sure how to correct that. Any help would be more than welcome!

Thank you very much! Cheers

Comment: Do you actually pay money for these ELearning Courses..? don't pay money when there are tons of free tutorials online using google as well as YouTube.. do a google search on `int32.TryParse` and you will quickly see what the problem and or issue is..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620565/int-tryparse-syntatic-sugar

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It´s a free class in college. The problem is that i can't use int32.TryParse, at least not yet. We can only make do with what we learned, like: int
x; var valor_x = Console.ReadLine(); if (int.TryParse(valor_x, out x))
{
Console.WriteLine(“Insert next number”);
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine(“A number was not inserted”);
return;
}

Comment: not necessary.. `Int.TryParse` is what I meant to say..

Comment: Oh ok, i will try to search and correct it then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to parse `nr_de_produtos` to an `int`:

```
int.TryParse(nr_de_produtos, out x)
```

But it's *already* an `int`:

```
var nr_de_produtos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

There's no need to convert an `int` to an `int`.

It *seems* like you expect that input to be a string which *might not* represent an `int`.  In which case your attempt to `TryParse` is the safer approach.  If that's the case, remove the `Parse` (which is less safe) and keep the input as a string:

```
var nr_de_produtos = Console.ReadLine();
```

---

**Edit:** As @Pikoh points out in a comment below, this block would also need to move:

```
switch (nr_de_produtos)
{
    //...
}
```

Since `nr_de_produtos` is no longer an `int`, you're going to want to switch on `x` *after* the `TryParse` operation.  (The compiler will hint at this when you make your changes.)

Comment: `var nr_de_produtos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` what if the user entered `X`

Comment: @MethodMan: Then `int.Parse()` would of course throw an exception.  It's probably safer for the OP to just keep the input as a string and use that `TryParse()` approach.  Clearly he doesn't need both :)

Comment: I know that it would what I am saying is that that line would error out if the op happened to read in `Y` for example

Comment: You miss something in your answer. The `switch` would need to be inside the `if (int.TryParse(nr_de_produtos, out x))`part

Comment: @Pikoh: Ah, good catch.  Indeed, some of the logic of this small program would need to be re-arranged a bit.  In lieu of completely re-writing it and doing the OP's homework for him though, I'll opt to address merely the error at hand.  Hopefully the OP can continue to drive toward a workable solution.

Comment: I suspected i was misusing those , but was unable to discern it. Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: I know David, noone wants to hive him the complete code. But the problem OP is a newbie, and would be nice to warn him that he should first check that the input is an int before trying to process it :)

Comment: @lapa_arkeo: I've updated the answer to include some hints based on helpful suggestions in these comments.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you all! As i said i'm a complete newbie in the programming world, yearning to learn, and am glad to find such a helpful community here. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

nr_de_produtos is already a integer

```
int.TryParse(nr_de_produtos, out x)
```

that's your mistake you should do something like

```
var nr_de_produtos = Console.ReadLine();
```

and then try to parse it to integer.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the swift reply! Cheers