# How to safely convert to Integer possible null values

Tags: c#, parsing, casting, null

```
var data = mockDataDB.Data.AsQueryable()
   .Select(x => new ProductDto
   {
       Id = Convert.ToInt64(x.id), // this might fail because id might be null 
       Quantity = Int32.TryParse(x.quantity, out int somenumber) ? x.quantity : (int?)null
   }
```

Issue with this code is that `x.id` and `x.quantity` might be null sometimes, they are both of type `string` and id and quantity are type of `int64` and `int32`..

How could I safely solve this?

Thanks

cheers

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed strings which might be null, and in case when they are not null I want to convert them to integers..

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Int32.TryParse(x.quantity, out int somenumber) ? somenumber : (int?)null`?  And how exactly does that not work?

Comment: `Id = int.TryParse(x.id, out int myID) ? myID : 0;` something along those lines should work.

Comment: @juharr but what should I put on somenumber, why I can't use something more generic / dynamic?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ what would be myID?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro if the parse succeeds, it would be `x.id` otherwise it returns `0`...

Comment: `myID` is the integer that the string `x.id` parsed to, if it parsed successfully. If `x.id` were `"56"` then `myID` would be `56`.

Comment: If `Quantity` is a `int` and not a `int?` then you obviously cannot set it to `(int?)null`.  You just have to decide what to set it to if the parsing fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to cast object to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745172/better-way-to-cast-object-to-int) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620565/int-tryparse-syntatic-sugar or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int

Comment: Please post the class definition, I'm interested in knowing the types of `x.Id` and `x.Quantity`

Comment: @Flater They are types of Int? and long

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: Then you are wrong about your claim that `x.Quantity` can be null, as `long` is not a nullable type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inline a TryParse with a ternary expression, provided you have a default value in mind for Id when it's null.

```
var data = mockDataDB.Data.AsQueryable()
   .Select(x => new ProductDto
   {
       Id = Int64.TryParse(x.id, out long val) ? val : 0L, 
       Quantity = Int32.TryParse(x.quantity, out int somenumber) ? somenumber : (int?)null
   }
```

Comment: but what is out long val and out int somenuber?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Those are declaring an [out parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier#calling-a-method-with-an-out-argument) as an inline value.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Those are the variables that contain the result of the parsing if it succeeds.

Comment: @juharr Why it cant be Quantity or Id which I'm trying to assing value to?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Properties and indexers can't be passed as out parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: `Id = Int64.TryParse(x.id, out int somenumber) ? somenumber : 0`

Answer (score -1):

Edited:
You should check if the String variable (x.id) is null. If it is, you set it to zero or some default value that you would want. If its not, proceed with the converting.
For example:

```
Id = (x.id == null) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt64(x.id);
```

Comment: `x.id.length()` that check if `x.id` is `null` will still throw an exception, because `id` is null... and the `equals` check is wrong

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.id)` does the job as well.

Comment: @AlexanderPowolozki there's more than one way, my comment was based on the answer's post, it's wrong.